# How i find that an item is edited complete in data grid in Flex?

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, flex4

please tell me somebody that, How i find that an item is edited complete in data grid in Flex ?

Actually i am using Flex 4 and develop application for AIR, I need to make an editable grid. all of my custom made editor is work but the native textinput type editor is not working.

Here is my complete code.

The third and last datagridcolumn is not update values when i edit it.

```
<mx:DataGrid id="id_RecentPatientGrid" includeInLayout="{includeGridInLayout}" visible="{includeGridInLayout}"
             rowCount="{id_RecentPatientGrid.dataProvider.length + 1}"
             width="100%" verticalScrollPolicy="off"
             editable="true"
             itemEditBegin="recentPatientGridItemEditBeginHandler(event)" 
             itemEditEnd="recentPatientGridItemEditEndHandler(event)"
             dataProvider="{immunizationCollection}" draggableColumns="false"  useRollOver="false"
             sortableColumns="false" fontFamily="Verdana" verticalGridLines="false"                 
             styleName="QIGrid"  
             headerStyleName="QIGridHeader" 
             headerBackgroundSkin="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.skins.dataGridSkins.DataGridHeaderBlueSkin"
             headerSeparatorSkin="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.skins.dataGridSkins.DatagridHeaderSeparatorSkin">
    <!--headerBackgroundSkin="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.skins.dataGridSkins.dataGridHeaderSkin"-->
    <mx:columns>
        <!-- Changes by baber waqas for displaying serial number  -->   
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Sr.#"       width="50" editable="false" labelFunction="displayRowNum" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Visit Date" width="50" editable="false" labelFunction="displayVisitDate" />
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Date Admin" width="60" editable="true"  dataField="DateAdmin"  editorDataField="text"> 
            <!--editorDataField="selectedDate" itemRenderer="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.custom.itemRenderer.DateRenderer4DG">-->

            <!--<mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <components:LabelDateField width="100%" editable="true" text="{outerDocument.id_DateAdmin.text}"
                                  selectableRange="{{rangeEnd : new Date()}}" />
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>-->
        </mx:DataGridColumn>                    
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="ImmunizationType.ImmunizationTypeName" width="120" headerText="Immunization" editorDataField="editorText" itemRenderer="mx.controls.Label">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <itemEditors:SparkComboBoxItemEditor dataProvider="{outerDocument.model.immunizationTypeDTOList}" labelField="ImmunizationTypeName" width="120"/>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="Dose" headerText="Dose" width="50" editorDataField="editorText">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <!--<VBImmunization:ImmunizationItemEditor dataProvider="{outerDocument.model.immunizationDoseList}" immunizationField="Dose" width="100%"/>
                    -->
                    <itemEditors:SparkComboBoxItemEditor dataProvider="{outerDocument.model.immunizationDoseList}" labelField="Dose" width="50" height="100%"/>
                    </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn dataField="LotNumber" headerText="Lot#" width="50" editorDataField="editorText">
            <mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <itemEditors:SparkComboBoxItemEditor dataProvider="{outerDocument.model.immunizationLotNumberList}" labelField="LotNumber" width="50"/>
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <mx:DataGridColumn headerText="Next Due" width="50"  dataField="NextDoseDue" editable="true" editorDataField="text"> <!-- editorDataField="selectedDate" itemRenderer="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.custom.itemRenderer.DateRenderer4DG">-->
            <!--<mx:itemEditor>
                <fx:Component>
                    <components:LabelDateField width="100%" editable="true" text="{outerDocument.id_NextDue.text}" />
                </fx:Component>
            </mx:itemEditor>-->
        </mx:DataGridColumn>
        <!--<mx:DataGridColumn dataField="VisitStatus" headerText="Status" itemRenderer="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.custom.itemRenderer.DateRenderer4DG" />-->
        <commons:DataGridColumnEx width="85" headerText="" editable="false" data="{deleteColumnData}" dataField="Note" property="PatientImmunizationId" section="{QIPopUpManager.IMMUNIZATION}" itemRenderer="com.adobe.Quivus.view.controls.custom.patientExamView.quickInput.commons.DeleteRecordRenderer" />
    </mx:columns> 
</mx:DataGrid>
```

Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do something as:

```
<components:LabelDateField id="df" 
                           width="100%" editable="true" 
                           text="{outerDocument.id_DateAdmin.text}"
                           selectableRange="{{rangeEnd : new Date()}}" 
                           change="{outerDocument.id_DateAdmin.text = df.selectedDate}"/>
```